# If a component is "unmounted" will it ever again be used?

Tags: reactjs

In react if a component is unmounted will that object ever again be reused?

Use case: let's say that component is sometime's shown from a higher level in an if statement.

If that component disappears a due to a state change then componentWillUnmount call will fire of course. When it later re-appears due to a state change, does react reuse this same component or does it create it from scratch? I would guess there is no guarantee of a new component, which is why both WillMount and WillUnmount exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, once it is unmounted, the instance will be garbage collected if there are no references, and separately, if a component is re-mounted, there will be a new instance.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4770#issuecomment-136928760